# Scroll div to the top of page using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have the following example almost working but would like to get the links on the right in the navbar to scroll the div to the top of the browser just below the navbar.  It works if there's more div left to be seen. The contact link scrolls the full div into view but not to the top of the page.(easier to see in full page mode)

```css
body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #home {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #about {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #portfolio {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #contact {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://codepen.io/rss81/pens/public/" target='_blank'>RSS81</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="home" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>About</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only way around this would be to add a bunch of padding to the bottom of the page so that there's enough space below the contact element to scroll it all the way to the top, which would not look very good.

Comment: Yup, @APAD1 is right, contact us section should have enough height so that it scroll to the top same like other links

Comment: interesting, I see the problem.  What about using jquery to adjust the browser dimensions

Comment: @DCR do you mean `window.resizeTo(width, height)` ?

Comment: yes, that might work

Comment: @DCR yes it will change browser dimension in height and width, So do you want me to put this option as answer so that it helps others too?

Comment: yes but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I have one possible solution for this. You could make the bottom most div take up the entire page's height so that it scrolls all the way to the top.

I made the bottom most div take up the entire screens space using

```
min-height:100vh;
```

```css
body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #home {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #about {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #portfolio {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #contact {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;
  min-height:100vh;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://codepen.io/rss81/pens/public/" target='_blank'>RSS81</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="home" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>About</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion.